# Compile MakeFile generated by WineMaker with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

i've converted with WineMaker a SLN (Visual Studio 14 Project) file, now i have the Makefile (WineMaker doesn't generated any output error) but GCC generated this error:

```
gcc: warning: Makefile: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

This is the MakeFile source : 
[Pastebin pasted MakeFile source](http://pastebin.com/raw/xjsgLasw)

This is the SLN Source : [Pastebin Pasted SLN source](http://pastebin.com/raw/jFcd3H7V)

Any solution Guys?
I've read another topic with this problem but i don't have understand the real problem and i suspect that the problem is another.

Comment: PS : I also tried with makedepend but nothing

Comment: This usually happens when you have -c in the link step. Try to remove if thats the case. Can you also paste the output of your make command with -n?

Comment: Makefile: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You've any solution for this? :)

Comment: What do you need?

Answer (score 0):

> Compile MakeFile generated by WineMaker with GCC

You can't compile a makefile, with GCC or any other compiler. You have attempted
to do something like:

```
gcc -c main.c Makefile
```

which doesn't make sense, and of which the result is exactly:

```
gcc: warning: Makefile: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

It looks like you fundamentally don't understand the use of GCC and GNU Make,
and it's beyond the purposes of Stackoverflow to fix that.
[Here is a fairly sound beginner's tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html).
For authoritative documentation, [here is the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) and
[here is the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Voting to close your question as Too Broad. Recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: AHAHHAHAHAHAHAHAHHHHAHAHAHHA , Thanks :D